How Do I Remove Pagination From A Single Blog Entry?
I am using the Pipdig theme Opulence, and am currently using a Static Front Page for a custom homepage, and a separate Static Posts page, so that I can decide where my viewers go.
I have also made it login only with user accounts that I must create myself. See where I am going with this?
The idea is that on each category, people are only allowed to view blog posts from that category. By default, this is what you get.
BUT I don't want my theme to show Next and Back for ALL posts on INDIVIDUAL blog posts.
This is vital given that the Wordpress will be used for a number of things, each requiring their own private section.
Thanks.

This sounds like a bit of an X/Y problem to me - if you want to prevent users from seeing certain content, this is something which should be implemented with user roles and permissions. Doing so will naturally prevent queries from producing content which users should not see - the pagination buttons would stop navigating to content which should be inaccessible. If you only remove buttons and such, you're just treating the symptoms of the issue, and it will take more work - users could still access that restricted content through other means (REST API, crafting querystrings, etc)

Ok. So I'm not a coder, so those terms don't mean anything to me. But the fact that it's all accessible even if I try and hide it, is what bothers me.
So it looks like you can choose which roles can read posts and pages etc. But there's no specific ID set, and I don't know how to do that. On the other hand, I don't necessarily mind certain content being accessed, I just don't want links to be displayed on the individual blog posts.

I do however want the whole wordpress to be login only, so that I can protect my privacy from ransomers online, and not have search engines listing me etc.
Although knowing how to set user permissions would be good too incase a few friends / family want to see my personal blog, but I don't want them to see my business posts etc.

This is really too broad a question for a Q&A site to solve, as it's going to require more custom development than we can supply in a simple code snippet.

As briefly discussed in the comments, WordPress is built to promote and provide several interfaces for it's content such that it is possible to discover and access posts in a number of different ways. This includes (but is not necessarily limited to) things such as

"Meta tags" embedded within every page's markup to assist other sites, services, and crawlers in interpreting and navigating the site.
The REST API which facilitates direct programmatic access to the data.
WordPress's core functionality of turning key/value pairs in the URL (specifically, the "querystring"/"search string") directly into a query for posts.
The actual face and UI of the site presented to end-users (all the navigation links and buttons and such).

Because of the diverse means by which content might be discovered and/or accessed, it's not very efficient to try and restrict access by way of altering each interface. And there exists the possibility that a plugin or future core development could introduce additional interfaces for the content, which means you may need to keep an eye out for such changes in order to keep things on lockdown.

Roles & Capabilities

As with most coding endeavors, there are many ways to achieve the desired outcome. I suggest Roles & Capabilities because I feel leveraging that mechanism for this purpose makes the most canonical sense, and should be broadly compatible with well-written extensions. But this is not an assertion that there are not other, or even easier solutions available.

Luckily, WordPress's Roles & Capabilities API provides a mechanism to solve this problem. By grouping users into Roles and telling WordPress what those Roles can access and how they can interact with those things (the Capabilities assigned to a Role, compared against the Capabilities which are assigned as requirements to content and interactions), WordPress will enforce these restrictions across all of it's interfaces. If a user's Roles lack the Capability to see some selection of posts, then these posts will be hidden from the user across all interfaces - no manner of navigation will betray their existence to the user, and a user's attempt to access restricted content directly will be denied.
The immediate obstacles to using this approach to fulfill your needs are that WordPress does not ship with a robust UI for managing Roles and Capabilities, and out of the box the Roles and Capabilities mechanism does not have functionality to restrict Capabilities on a per-term basis (i.e. individual categories). But like much of WordPress, the Roles and Capabilities system is itself extensible.
So you will need to either find a plugin which may provide these things for you, or at least the latter issue must be addressed by custom code.
Premade Plugins
I don't have any experience with such plugins so I cannot provide a well-informed suggestion, but I will say that most of the free plugins which I found in a brief search only provide an interface for the core ability to restrict a user's management of a whole taxonomy - that is, whether they can add or edit or assign individual terms - and they do not implement the per-term access restriction which you are looking for. I do see some premium options providing such an implementation however, such as AAM and Restrict.
Custom Development
To code such a feature by hand would likely be somewhat convoluted owed to the learning curve associated with the Roles and Capabilities system, but broadly, I think it might be fairly directly accomplished by adding a list of Roles to terms' meta-data, then comparing those roles against a user's within a map_meta_cap filter, producing either the current post's read_post meta capability or the do_not_allow capability to enforce whether or not they can read the post. I think this would be somewhat hackish, but could likely be made a whole lot more robust by introducing new primitive and meta capabilities for terms.
